# F#: Can the match expression not return sequences when mapped to from non sequence type?

Tags: f#

I am trying to create a recursive function that is conditionally calls itself and so far is is defined as follows:

```
let rec crawlPage (page : String, nestingLevel : int) =    
    HtmlDocument.Load(page)
    |> fun m -> m.CssSelect("a")
    |> List.map(fun a -> a.AttributeValue("href"))
    |> Seq.distinctBy id
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> baseUrl + x)
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> 
        match nestingLevel with
        // Compiler says it is expecting a but given seq<a> in reference to the recursive call
        | _ when (nestingLevel > 0) -> crawlPage(x, (nestingLevel - 1)) 
        | _ when (nestingLevel <= 0) -> ignore
        | _ -> (* To silence warnigs.*) ignore
    )
```

It is that the `Seq.map (fun x -> ...)` cannot handle the return sequence or can the match condition not handle the returned sequence? Given that the crawlPage is underlined by the compiler it seems that the match statement cannot handle the seq returned so how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that all the matching branches must return the same type, so you have to:

1. Replace `ignore` with `Seq.singleton x` to indicate that this branch yields nothing more except the `x` itself.
2. At the end, concat (flat map) the `seq<seq<string>>` to transform it to a `seq<string>`.

The code would be:

```
|> Seq.map (fun x -> 
    match nestingLevel with
    | _ when (nestingLevel > 0) -> crawlPage(x, (nestingLevel - 1)) 
    | _ -> Seq.singleton x)
|> Seq.concat
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing post answers your specific question, but I think it is worth noting that there are a few other changes that could be done to your code snippet. Some of those are a matter of personal preference, but I believe they make your code simpler:

- You can use sequence comprehension, which lets you handle recursive calls nicely using `yield!` (and non-recursive using `yield`)
- You do not actually need `match`, because you have just two branches that are more easily tested using ordinary `if`
- I would also avoid the `|> fun m -> m.Xyz` pattern, because it's not necessary here.

With all those tweaks, my preferred version of the code snippet would be:

```
let rec crawlPage (page : String, nestingLevel : int) = seq {
    let urls = 
        HtmlDocument.Load(page).CssSelect("a")
        |> List.map(fun a -> a.AttributeValue("href"))
        |> Seq.distinctBy id
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> baseUrl + x)

    for x in urls do
        if nestingLevel > 0 then
            yield! crawlPage(x, (nestingLevel - 1)) 
        else 
            yield x }
```